# How can I "persist" a rails app locale?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, locale, rails-i18n

I created a rails website using rails 5, and I added the possibility to translate the website in french in english (french is by default)

When I set the locale in english, everything is fine, but when I click on a link, the website goes back to french, and the user needs to translate the website again

Is there a way to keep the locale through the pages the user will go on?

Thank you in advance

**EDIT**

I added my application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_filter :set_locale

  def set_admin_locale
    I18n.locale = :fr
  end

  def default_url_options
    { locale: I18n.locale }
  end

  private
  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
    Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:locale]= I18n.locale
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of cluttering your whole application with `posts_path(locale: params[:locale])` you can use [`default_url_options`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#default-url-options).

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def default_url_options
    { locale: I18n.locale }
  end
end
```

What this does is whenever you generate a url with the url helpers it will attach the current locale (the locale used in the current request) to the url query string.

So if the user requests `/users?locale=se` and the rendered view contains `link_to(@user.name, @user)` it will have the path `/users/1?locale=se`.

Comment: I pasted this in my `application_controller.rb`, but it didn't change anything... Is there anything else I have to do to make this work?

Comment: Try restarting your server. It could be a cache issue

Comment: Sorry for the time it took, so I restarted the server and tried on another computer, but i didn't work on both cases. I'll edit my question to show my application_controller.rb

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the current locale via the route params to any other routes:

```
 link_to 'Posts', posts_path(locale: params[:locale])
```

It will then carry across url requests. Just be sure to do the same in your redirect calls from the controllers.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html is a good reference for setting up I18n

Comment: Let's say I want to head to "biography", will the link look like, `<%= link_to 'Biography', '/biography', locale: params[:locale]`?

Comment: The second param accepts a hash, which is the same format as for `url_for`. The docs here show examples better than i can: https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiE54jdi97OAhXErB4KHTs1A6MQFgglMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapidock.com%2Frails%2Factioncontroller%2Fbase%2Furl_for&usg=AFQjCNGyIUdeGPANKXlQrIuAFuzNnKbu5g&sig2=4QlMg3BdzaBZf_jzAC2NOA